# Powershell Recipientcount Sum per Sender

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want the script to calculate all sent mail from a unique e-mail address. At the moment it only counts the amount of mail sent and it does not add the total number of recipients per mail. There needs to be a sum of the recipient count per mail. I have the following powershell line:

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -resultsize unlimited -Start $bstart -End $bend | 
 where-object {$_.EventID -eq "RECEIVE"} | select-object TimeStamp, Sender, RecipientCount | 
    Group-Object Sender | select-object Name, Count | Sort-Object Count -descending | 
      select-object Name, Count -first 20 | convertto-html
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what the output is from your current command?

Comment: The output is as follow:
[link]https://andry.stackstorage.com/index.php/s/0oKzeip0MC3DrqV

Comment: You might want to look at Deliver events instead of Receive events.  Receive events are recorded before DL expansion, and may not reflect the actual number of recipients the email will get delivered to.